# XSLT: Change an attribute based on a condition from another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Although there are many similar questions, none of them seem to answer my requirements.

I would like to change the *from* attribute of the element *invoice:transport*  within my XML based on the *ean_party* attribute of the element *invoice:insurance*.

The input XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<invoice:response xmlns:invoice="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" language="de" modus="production" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice generalInvoiceResponse_440.xsd">
    <invoice:processing>
        <!--original "from" attribute-->
        <invoice:transport from="7601003000123" to="7601003000456">
            <invoice:via sequence_id="1" via="7601003000789"/>
        </invoice:transport>
    </invoice:processing>
    <invoice:payload copy="false" credit_advice="false" response_timestamp="1515671999" storno="false" type="invoice">
        <invoice:invoice request_date="2018-01-01T00:00:00" request_id="999999" request_timestamp="1515671999"/>
        <invoice:body>
            <invoice:insurance ean_party="7601003000999"/>
        </invoice:body>
    </invoice:payload>
</invoice:response>
```

The output XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<invoice:response xmlns:invoice="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" language="de" modus="production" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice generalInvoiceResponse_440.xsd">
    <invoice:processing>
        <!--replaced "from" attribute with ean_party attribute-->
        <invoice:transport from="7601003000999" to="7601003000456">
            <invoice:via sequence_id="1" via="7601003000789"/>
        </invoice:transport>
    </invoice:processing>
    <invoice:payload copy="false" credit_advice="false" response_timestamp="1515671999" storno="false" type="invoice">
        <invoice:invoice request_date="2018-01-01T00:00:00" request_id="999999" request_timestamp="1515671999"/>
        <invoice:body>
            <!--ean_party attribute that matches my condition-->
            <invoice:insurance ean_party="7601003000999"/>
        </invoice:body>
    </invoice:payload>
</invoice:response>
```

I have tried adapting the XSLT from another post, but I didn't work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--declare condition for transport block-->
    <xsl:variable name="mandant">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//transport = '7601003000123'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'7601003000999'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="//transport"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>        
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--dynamic template for replacing current value to condition value-->    
    <xsl:template name="value-to-replace">
        <xsl:param name="param.str"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.target"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($param.str, $param.target)">                    
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($param.str, $param.target), $param.replacement, substring-after($param.str, $param.target))"/>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.str"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--replace value in transport block with mandant variable condition-->
    <xsl:template match="@from">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">                                    
            <xsl:call-template name="value-to-replace">                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.str" select="."/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.target" select="//transport"/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.replacement" select="$mandant"/>                   
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>                      
    </xsl:template>             
    <!--copy all nodes-->    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Great post with respect of providing demodata but:  _... it did not work ..._ So we are supposed to copare your original and the should_look_like_this one and  puzzle out wheres the difference and then read through the xlst and puzzle out whats wrong to help out? Maybe you could drop 2-3 sencentec of what " did not work" and maybe mark the places in the xml with `<!-- -->`  as to where should what happen?  Would improve the qeustion a bunch. +1 non the less.

Comment: Also not the XSLT is not well-formed, as it looks like some lines have been removed (There is a closing `</xsl:call-template>` tag, but no matching opening one).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to update my code examples with more comments. I also corrected the XSLT, as pointed out by Tim C, it was not well-formed because forgot to delete some lines before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with the how you reference the `transport` element

```
 <xsl:value-of select="//transport"/>
```

There are two problems here...

1. You have not taken into account namespaces. In your input XML the `transport` element is in a namespace (as signified by the use of the `invoice:` prefix. But your XSLT is looking for `transport` elements in no namespace
2. The expression is selecting the value of the `transport` element, but you want the value of the `@from` attribute.

So it should be this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="//invoice:transport/@from"/>
```

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!--declare condition for transport block-->
<xsl:variable name="mandant">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//invoice:transport/@from = '7601003000123'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'7601003000999'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//invoice:transport/@from"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
</xsl:variable>
<!--dynamic template for replacing current value to condition value-->    
<xsl:template name="value-to-replace">
    <xsl:param name="param.str"/>
    <xsl:param name="param.target"/>
    <xsl:param name="param.replacement"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($param.str, $param.target)">                    
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($param.str, $param.target), $param.replacement, substring-after($param.str, $param.target))"/>              
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$param.str"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!--replace value in transport block with mandant variable condition-->
<xsl:template match="@from">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">                                    
        <xsl:call-template name="value-to-replace">                       
            <xsl:with-param name="param.str" select="."/>                       
            <xsl:with-param name="param.target" select="//invoice:transport/@from"/> 
            <xsl:with-param name="param.replacement" select="$mandant"/>                   
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>                      
</xsl:template>             
<!--copy all nodes-->    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I can't help wondering if your XSLT is too complicated. If you are just replacing one complete value with another, then I think you can simplify your XSLT to this, based on your original requirement...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:invoice="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="invoice:transport/@from">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="//invoice:insurance/@ean_party" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just added the Output method to XML and now it works! Perfect, thank you very much!